# Unable to call JavaScript Function from code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, scriptmanager

I'm working in application build in ASP.Net environment, I wanted to call JavaScript Function from the code behind in C#.

I tried using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript() method, it hit error saying "The name 'ScriptManager' does not exist in the current contect", I already include the namespace System.Web.UI and yet still got this error.

Any idea how can this happen? or there is a better workaround rather that using ScripManager to trigger JavaScript function from code behind?

thank you in advanced.

Comment: From where exactly (from what event handler) in your code behind are you calling the `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` method?

Answer (score 1):

```
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "GenerateMatrixText", script, true);
```

Comment: If this doesnot work then there might be issue with the installed version of ajax

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Page.RegisterStartupScript("some_name","javascript function enclosed with script tag")
```

Answer (score 0):

Read more here on MSDN about RegisterStartupScript http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx

Also make sure that you have a FORM on the page. If there is no form on the page then the script will fail to execute.

Comment: I guess it might be due to no FORM on the page but a user crontrol, I used Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartUpScript() and the JavaScript function is not working. Any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. Do you want to call a javascript function simultaneously when the code behind code is executing? If that is the case then it is NOT possible. 
Javascript runs on the client side and code behind runs on the server side. A control is either client side or server side, it cannot be simultaneously at both the sides.

What `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` does is that at the time of document load on your browser it add a block of script at the bottom of your page. This will allow you to call that newly added javascript code from the javascript code of your page. This allows you to create custom javascript code at the backend and push it to page load.

If there is some other scenario then please clarify.